# applicationWillResignActive called by iOS alerts too. How to avoid this?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I use `applicationWillResignActive` to display the splash image when my app is in background (see code-snippet). Reason: I don't want private data of the app be visible when my app is in background on iOS 7 and the user presses the Home button twice.

```
splashWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
splashWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
[splashWindow addSubview:splashViewController.view];
[splashWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The problem is that `applicationWillResignActive` is also fired when iOS shows an alert because some certificate is about to expire. How can I fix this? Do I need to take another approach to display the splash image in background?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Why don't you use applicationWillEnterBackground notification in the AppDelegate?

Comment: cause that event never gets called

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the applicationWillEnterBackground to open a blank screen/your splash image and switch back to your normal screen with applicationWillEnterForeground.

Comment: - (void)applicationWillEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application never gets called (in iOS7)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I could not change the iOS behaviour as described but I used:

```
[self.window addSubview:splashViewController.view];
```

instead of the code-snippet above. The iOS alert still makes the splash appear but I hide it again in `applicationDidBecomeActive` with `[splashViewController.view removeFromSuperview];`
The splash now disappears when the alert is answered with OK or Cancel.